# Вопрос по коду таймера

Tags: javascript, таймер, countdowntimer

Есть такой код, он работает так, что после окончания обратного отсчёта, он продолжает работать, но крутит уже в плюс, то есть, не останавливается. Как и что заменить, чтобы таймер останавливался и обнулялся?
Сразу скажу, что в JS пока не разбираюсь.

```js
go: function() {
  var idx = 0;

  $r.time = (new Date().getTime()) - $r.countdown_to_time;


  for (var r_key in $r.rings) $r.unit(idx++, r_key, $r.rings[r_key]);

  setTimeout($r.go, $r.update_interval);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($r.time < 0) {
  for(var r_key in $r.rings) {
    $r.unit(idx++, r_key, $r.rings[r_key]);
  }
  setTimeout($r.go, $r.update_interval);
} else {
  // обнулите счетчик
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Счётчик останавливается, но не обнуляется почему-то.

Comment: @Plutooo Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа. Смысл фразы "счетчик не обнуляется" мне неизвестен.

Comment: Отредактировал свой вопрос."Не обнуляется" - имеется ввиду то, что по достижении времени таймер не сбрасывается и не показываются нули везде.

Comment: @Plutooo Какие "нули везде"? Я должен догадаться, где должны появиться нули, и по этим догадкам написать код?