# Как указать id для таймера?

Tags: таймер

Есть index.js, сразу скажу, что не я писал его (в JS не спец). Помогите наглядным советом, пожалуйста, как в этом коде указать/задать id для таймера, чтобы можно было использовать два таймера на одной странице? А то когда добавляешь второй, первый перестаёт считать время.

И ещё вопрос, как правильно сделать фоновый цвет для first circle, чтобы он не занимал половину границы круга, при увеличении r_thickness.

```
var ringer = {
  //countdown_to: "10/31/2014",
  countdown_to: "10/31/2016",
  rings: {
    'DAYS': { 
      s: 86400000, // mseconds in a day,
      max: 365
    },
    'HOURS': {
      s: 3600000, // mseconds per hour,
      max: 24
    },
    'MINUTES': {
      s: 60000, // mseconds per minute
      max: 60
    },
    'SECONDS': {
      s: 1000,
      max: 60
    },
    'MICROSEC': {
      s: 10,
      max: 100
    }
   },
  r_count: 5,
  r_spacing: 10, // px
  r_size: 100, // px
  r_thickness: 2, // px
  update_interval: 11, // ms


  init: function(){

    $r = ringer;
    $r.cvs = document.createElement('canvas'); 

    $r.size = { 
      w: ($r.r_size + $r.r_thickness) * $r.r_count + ($r.r_spacing*($r.r_count-1)), 
      h: ($r.r_size + $r.r_thickness) 
    };



    $r.cvs.setAttribute('width',$r.size.w);           
    $r.cvs.setAttribute('height',$r.size.h);
    $r.ctx = $r.cvs.getContext('2d');
    $(document.body).append($r.cvs);
    $r.cvs = $($r.cvs);    
    $r.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    $r.actual_size = $r.r_size + $r.r_thickness;
    $r.countdown_to_time = new Date($r.countdown_to).getTime();
    $r.cvs.css({ width: $r.size.w+"px", height: $r.size.h+"px" });
    $r.go();
  },
  ctx: null,
  go: function(){
    var idx=0;

    $r.time = (new Date().getTime()) - $r.countdown_to_time;


    for(var r_key in $r.rings) $r.unit(idx++,r_key,$r.rings[r_key]);      

    setTimeout($r.go,$r.update_interval);
  },
  unit: function(idx,label,ring) {
    var x,y, value, ring_secs = ring.s;
    value = parseFloat($r.time/ring_secs);
    $r.time-=Math.round(parseInt(value)) * ring_secs;
    value = Math.abs(value);

    x = ($r.r_size*.5 + $r.r_thickness*.5);
    x +=+(idx*($r.r_size+$r.r_spacing+$r.r_thickness));
    y = $r.r_size*.5;
    y += $r.r_thickness*.5;


    // calculate arc end angle
    var degrees = 360-(value / ring.max) * 360.0;
    var endAngle = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);

    $r.ctx.save();

    $r.ctx.translate(x,y);
    $r.ctx.clearRect($r.actual_size*-0.5,$r.actual_size*-0.5,$r.actual_size,$r.actual_size);

    // first circle
    $r.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(128,128,128,0.2)";
    $r.ctx.beginPath();
    $r.ctx.arc(0,0,$r.r_size/2,0,2 * Math.PI, 2);
    $r.ctx.lineWidth =$r.r_thickness;
    $r.ctx.stroke();
    $r.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(128,128,128,0.6)";
    $r.ctx.fill();

    // second circle
    $r.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(253, 128, 1, 0.9)";
    $r.ctx.beginPath();
    $r.ctx.arc(0,0,$r.r_size/2,0,endAngle, 1);
    $r.ctx.lineWidth =$r.r_thickness;
    $r.ctx.stroke();

    // label
    $r.ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";

    $r.ctx.font = '12px Helvetica';
    $r.ctx.fillText(label, 0, 23);
    $r.ctx.fillText(label, 0, 23);   

    $r.ctx.font = 'bold 40px Helvetica';
    $r.ctx.fillText(Math.floor(value), 0, 10);

    $r.ctx.restore();
  }
}

ringer.init();
```

Comment: где второй таймер, и где объявлена переменная `$r`?

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? -  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/930731/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: А как-то спокойнее можно отвечать? Я ведь написал, что в JS не разбираюсь, если бы разбирался, то не просил бы советов. К тому же, в обеих темах написал, что код/файл не мой, не я его писал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно создавать несколько таймеров, вы можете создать функцию-фабрику, которая будет возвращать объект таймера.

```js
function ringerFactory(date) {
  let $r;
  const ringer = {
    //countdown_to: "10/31/2014",
    countdown_to: date,
    rings: {
      'DAYS': {
        s: 86400000, // mseconds in a day,
        max: 365
      },
      'HOURS': {
        s: 3600000, // mseconds per hour,
        max: 24
      },
      'MINUTES': {
        s: 60000, // mseconds per minute
        max: 60
      },
      'SECONDS': {
        s: 1000,
        max: 60
      },
      'MICROSEC': {
        s: 10,
        max: 100
      }
    },
    r_count: 5,
    r_spacing: 10, // px
    r_size: 100, // px
    r_thickness: 2, // px
    update_interval: 11, // ms


    init: function() {

      $r = ringer;

      $r.cvs = document.createElement('canvas');

      $r.size = {
        w: ($r.r_size + $r.r_thickness) * $r.r_count + ($r.r_spacing * ($r.r_count - 1)),
        h: ($r.r_size + $r.r_thickness)
      };


      $r.cvs.setAttribute('width', $r.size.w);
      $r.cvs.setAttribute('height', $r.size.h);
      $r.ctx = $r.cvs.getContext('2d');
      $(document.body).append($r.cvs);
      $r.cvs = $($r.cvs);
      $r.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      $r.actual_size = $r.r_size + $r.r_thickness;
      $r.countdown_to_time = new Date($r.countdown_to).getTime();
      $r.cvs.css({
        width: $r.size.w + "px",
        height: $r.size.h + "px"
      });
      $r.go();
    },
    ctx: null,
    go: function() {
      var idx = 0;

      $r.time = (new Date().getTime()) - $r.countdown_to_time;


      for (var r_key in $r.rings) $r.unit(idx++, r_key, $r.rings[r_key]);

      setTimeout($r.go, $r.update_interval);
    },
    unit: function(idx, label, ring) {
      var x, y, value, ring_secs = ring.s;
      value = parseFloat($r.time / ring_secs);
      $r.time -= Math.round(parseInt(value)) * ring_secs;
      value = Math.abs(value);

      x = ($r.r_size * .5 + $r.r_thickness * .5);
      x += +(idx * ($r.r_size + $r.r_spacing + $r.r_thickness));
      y = $r.r_size * .5;
      y += $r.r_thickness * .5;


      // calculate arc end angle
      var degrees = 360 - (value / ring.max) * 360.0;
      var endAngle = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);

      $r.ctx.save();

      $r.ctx.translate(x, y);
      $r.ctx.clearRect($r.actual_size * -0.5, $r.actual_size * -0.5, $r.actual_size, $r.actual_size);

      // first circle
      $r.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(128,128,128,0.2)";
      $r.ctx.beginPath();
      $r.ctx.arc(0, 0, $r.r_size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, 2);
      $r.ctx.lineWidth = $r.r_thickness;
      $r.ctx.stroke();
      $r.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(128,128,128,0.6)";
      $r.ctx.fill();

      // second circle
      $r.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(253, 128, 1, 0.9)";
      $r.ctx.beginPath();
      $r.ctx.arc(0, 0, $r.r_size / 2, 0, endAngle, 1);
      $r.ctx.lineWidth = $r.r_thickness;
      $r.ctx.stroke();

      // label
      $r.ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";

      $r.ctx.font = '12px Helvetica';
      $r.ctx.fillText(label, 0, 23);
      $r.ctx.fillText(label, 0, 23);

      $r.ctx.font = 'bold 40px Helvetica';
      $r.ctx.fillText(Math.floor(value), 0, 10);

      $r.ctx.restore();
    }
  }
  return ringer;
}

var ringer = ringerFactory('10/31/2019');
ringer.init();

var ringer2 = ringerFactory('3/31/2020');
ringer2.init();

var ringer3 = ringerFactory('10/31/2018');
ringer3.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Я правильно понимаю, что id в таком варианте будут first, second и third? Если так, то не пойму, как их указать потом.

Comment: @Plutooo поправил. Никаких id там нету. Они и не нужны.

Comment: Почему-то думается, что без id не получится сделать так, чтобы два таймера работали независимо на одной странице. Или просто там надо будет много переписывать?

Comment: @Plutooo Сейчас в примере в сниппете три таймера работают независимо на одной странице. В чем вы видите проблему?

Comment: Работают, но с разными датами получится такое же сделать?

Comment: @Plutooo Укажите разные даты, будут разные даты. Я обновлю пример.

Comment: @Plutooo чем вас не устраивает мой ответ? Почему убрали галочку как верный?

Comment: Степан, просто изменил вопрос, код тот же, вопрос другой. И честно сказать, не пойму, как здесь всё работает и по какому принципу можно здесь что-то спрашивать.

Comment: @Plutooo здесь принято так. В одном вопросе, один конкретный вопрос. Если вопрос решили, то принимаете ответ. Если появился другой вопрос, то задаете другой вопрос.

Comment: @Plutooo ознакомьтесь еще пожалуйста с этой информацией https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2948/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0